How to display 4k image on AndroidTV using Java?
I'm writing an AndroidTV app that displays a 4K image on a 4K device e.g. Firestick 4K. As AndroidTV and FireTV both seem to report their UI as 1920x1080 regardless of whether the device is 4K, how can this be done?
If I use this code to report the dimensions in pixels:
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
if (windowManager != null) {
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
}
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

Width and height will be 1920x1080 even if the device is 4K and connected to a 4K monitor @ 2160p.
My layout file uses a simple FrameLayout:
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.app.my.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/myframe"
    android:layout_gravity="center"    
>

The imageView itself and the frame reports as 1920x1080 using getWidth() and getHeight().
Any help would be much appreciated.

have you tried an emulator that is 4k? There is nothing you as a developer have to do to say its 4k or not, it up to the device

Old but possibly relavent: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#4K-display
